# Browsing through a linked List

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to create a sparse(linked) structure, which each node pointing to all of its children (5 in total). 
Till now, I've only created the first node (called "root"). I am trying to traverse the linked structure, hoping that the program will return 'root'. 
It is giving me a segmentation fault.

main class

```
Item n;

newDirectory();
printf("Folder root has been created.");

printf("Enter the name of the directory you want to traverse: ");
scanf("%s", n.name);
browseItem(n);
```

struct I created

```
typedef struct Directory{
   //name of the file
   char name[16];
   //file content
   char value[80];
   _Bool isLeaf;

   //if folder status = 1, if txt status = 2, if empty status = 0
   int status;
   struct Directory *firstchild;
   struct Directory *secondchild;
   struct Directory *thirdchild;
   struct Directory *fourthchild;
   struct Directory *fifthchild;
}Item;
```

class Function where the struct resides also I included

```
//points to the first node: node "root" 
Item *head;

//creates the first (head) node: "root"
void newDirectory(){
  head = (Item *)malloc(sizeof(Item));

  if(head == NULL){
      printf("Unable to allocate memory.");
  }else{
      strcpy(head->name,"root");
      head->status = 1;
      head->firstchild = NULL;
      head->secondchild = NULL;
      head->thirdchild = NULL;
      head->fourthchild= NULL;
      head->fifthchild = NULL;
  }
}


void browseItem(Item n) {
   //how do I find the location of n
   Item *tmp;
   tmp = (Item *)malloc(sizeof(Item));
   if(head == NULL){
       printf("List is empty!");
   }else{
      tmp = **location of n**;
      while(tmp!=NULL){
          printf("%s", tmp->name);
          tmp = tmp->firstchild;
          tmp = tmp->secondchild;
          tmp = tmp->thirdchild;
          tmp = tmp->fourthchild;
          tmp = tmp->fifthchild;
      }
   }
}
```

My question is how do I first search the location of n, so that 
the the program starts traversing from that node. And if I had
more nodes coming from root, would the children be traversed as well?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's the desired behavior of browseItem(..)? i see no return value. Also, this isn't a linked-list but rather a tree. Furthermore, in such connected structures the search is done via recursion easier. browseItem should take two arguments. 1 the element to be searched, 2. the (temp) root node to start searching. So the first time you call browseItem(n, head); and the other times browseItem(n, head->children);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segfault is usually caused by data being transferred incorrectly. There are a couple of issues with your code and your logic. Let me try to answer all of your questions as best I can:

First, your linked list, isn't really a linked list, it's a tree. A linked list will point to the next node. This is a singly linked list, and a doubly linked list will point to the next node, and the previous node. They're all the same thing, except a tree simply has more children, whereas a linked list simply has a 1 children, and a doubly linked list will also have a pointer to the parent (or previous element).

Your second question seems to be, how do I get to root?

> "I am trying to traverse the linked structure, hoping that the program will return 'root'."

Currently, your code is like this: `root--> child 1, child 2, child 3` (which is a tree). If you want your code to be a linked list instead, it would have to be `root--> child1 --> child2 --> child3` ... and so on. However, your linked list is a singly linked list, which means you can can only go forwards, not backwards. If you want to go back to root, it would be `null<--root--> <--child1--> <--child 2 --> <-- ... -->`, and so on (you would have to have a pointer, pointing back to the previous node, just like a doubly linked list).

So for your question of how do I find n?

> //how do I find the location of n

You can only do that if you start with root, and traverse through the linked list that way. The simplest way to do that using a linked list would be:

```
Item tmp = head->child1;
while (tmp != null)
{
    if (tmp -> name == n)
    {
         print "Found n!" + tmp->name
         break;
    }
    tmp = tmp -> nextChild;

}
```

This code is just a pseudocode to make it look simpler.

If it is a tree, then use'll have to use a Breadth First algorithm, or a Depth first algorithm to find n. If your code is trying to mimic a file structure, a tree should be used, not a linked list.